# How to increment variable every two cycle if condition exist in a while loop

Tags: php, variables, while-loop, increment, cycle

I have an array from database into a loop "while" cycle and i need every two cycle if two row have same value increment +1 a variable.

every 2 cycles if there is a winner and immediately after a winner again the $cnt variable increases by 1 if instead there is a winner(vincente) and immediately after a loser(perdente), no increment and this for the whole array, 2 lines at a time.

```
$cnt=0;
While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){    

    if ($row['result']=="vincente"){                
            
    }
        else {
            
    }
}
```

I try with this but no idea to continue.

Comment: You could keep a separate variable that counts in which row you are, and if that value is even then you check for the "vincente" row. This might be a bit spacially inefficient (but well it's php, nobody will notice)

Comment: Just increment `$cnt` every time you find the winning value and then do `$cnt = floor($cnt/2)` after the loop. You could also do this logic directly in your sql: `SELECT FLOOR(COUNT(*)/2.0) as winning_count FROM yourtable WHERE result = 'vicente'` if you wanted to push the processing back to your db server.

Comment: Increment count and use modulo for every nth. `if(0 === $cnt % $n) {}`.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain myself well, I mean that every 2 cycles if there is a winner and immediately after a winner again the $cnt variable increases by 1 if instead there is a winner(vincente) and immediately after a loser(perdente), no increment and this for the whole array, 2 lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two items simultaneously. Here is example how you can do it.

```php
// making a Generator, that will return pair of elements on each iteration
function fetchPairs($result) {
  // initialize array, which will store elements
  $pair = [];
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // add each element in array
    $pair[] = $row;
    // if there is 2 elements..
    if (count($pair) === 2) {
      // ..yield them and..
      yield $pair;
      // ..clear array
      $pair = [];
    }
  }
}

$count = 0;
// in this `foreach` each iteration now returns pair of two elements;
foreach (fetchPairs($res) as [$first, $second]) { // you can use $pair instead of destructing list into $first and $second varialbes
   // check both items are 'vincente'
   if ($first['result'] === 'vincente' && $second['result'] === 'vincente') {
      $count += 1;
   }
}
```